# Making dropdown boxs formating more responsive

Tags: css

I trying to make my implementation of my drop down boxes more responsive. Specifically with the margins between them. I tried using percentages and ems with the margins but nothing seems to work how I would picture it on mobile (see picture). Theres is just too much blank space.
Here's the code: [Codepen](https://codepen.io/Dex_BC/pen/KKwyoJe)

```
.wrap-collabsible {
margin-bottom: 10%;
margin-top: 15%;}
```

[image: Example]

Comment: You could try using media queries

Comment: You could try using vector units so it changes based on the width of the screen. `margin-top: 3vw;`